# ¿Como puedo hacer que mi botón 'Guardar' detecte automaticamente que se ha presionado la tecla enter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Me encuentro aprendiendo React y estoy realizando un pequeño ToDoList, me gustaría que cuando se termine de rellenar el título de la tarea y la descripción de la misma, al momento de presionar enter en el teclado, se haga una especie de 'autofocus' a mi botón de 'Guardar', tengo entendido que esto se podría hacer con JS. Les dejo mi código por acá.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(title, description);
    createTask({
      title,
      description,
    });
    settitle(""), setDescription("");
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="Task"
        placeholder="Escribe tu tarea"
        onChange={(e) => {
          settitle(e.target.value);
        }}
        value={title}
        autoFocus
      />
      <textarea
        placeholder="Escribe la descripción de la tarea"
        onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
        value={description}
      ></textarea>
      // Creo que la funcionalidad de la que hablo debería ir acá como un evento del botón
      <button>Guardar</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Realicé toda la lógica de limpiar el pequeño formulario cuando el usuario de guardar a la tarea, solo quiero agregar esa pequeña funcionalidad extra que no está de más.

Comment: si al botón le añades la propiedad type="submit" debería de funcionar

Answer (score 0):

En React, los inputs tienen la propiedad de **onKeyDown**, esta escucha el evento cuando precionas una tecla (cualquiera), debes de pasarle el evento leer la propiedad key, con un condicional te aseguras que sea  'Enter' y haces la funcionalidad que necesitas.

Mira un ejemplo.

```
const App = () => {

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      //La logica que necesitas iría aquí
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        id="message"
        name="message"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```